# How i get URL of steam apps in c#

Tags: c#, launcher, app-launcher

I'm making a application for steam games. Because shortcuts steal zone from desktop ,so i make this project for this. I want add a "drop file here to add list" when he put to shortcut on program i need get the app id, then it will automatically add to list.I added the drop file script!! But i dont know how to get URL title from assembly..There is a screenshot. I want get url from shortcut like this.

[SCREENSHOT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUFc7.png)

[SCREENSHOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRzRv.png)

!! I made the drop file script.. I just have problems at get url script.

Comment: I think you should be able to parse the shortcut (.url-file) with an INI-file parser.

Comment: It's not very clear and specific question on C#. it seems you are asking how to read url from screenshot. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Opening steam applications is very simple, if you know the location of your steam.exe.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe","steam://rungameid/730");
```

In my case (i think its default as well) you can start an application just by giving the path of the steam.exe and passing the content of the shortcut as argument.

Edit: 
If you want to get the argument value you can just read the File using

```
File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

And get the argument from the string, which will then look like this:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/Golf With Your Friends.url");
        string argument = lines.ToList().FirstOrDefault(item => { return item.Contains("steam://"); }).Replace("URL=", "");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe", argument);
```

Comment: One funny thing: You can not enter matchmaking in cs:go when starting it this way because VAC cannot verify the session. Just experienced it :D

Comment: What do you mean with "url"?

Comment: If you run game with Process.Start(steam://rungameid/xxx) it will verify steam session so VAC session will be verified

Comment: Do you now have the answer you wanted?